# SQL Select Time Difference Between VARCHAR Column Types

Tags: sql, oracle, time, varchar, difference

I have a table in my database which has two columns, one `START_TIME` and the other `END_TIME`. The columns are of type `VARCHAR2`.

I want to select the time difference between these two columns.

Just to know what kind of data these columns contains I have selected the data from these columns below.

This is the result of `SELECT DISTINCT start_time FROM table_name` :

```
15:20
22.30
16:00
24:00
07:00
06:55
6:45
23:50
6.5
15.20
19:00
0:00
1600
16
19
15:00
6:50
7
15:30
23.50
24
14.75
23
15:45
00:15
```

and this is the result of `SELECT DISTINCT end_time FROM table_name`

```
07:00
16:00
24:00
6:45
15:35
07
00
16
08:00
07:20
7.25
15:00
0700
7
15:30
15
06:45
07.00
24
15.30
7:00
23
15:45
00:15
```

What can be done?

Comment: There is not enough information right now to match a start_time with an end_time. Is both of these columns from the same table (looks like it, but good to be sure)?

Comment: Yuk. You need to fix whatever is writing that into the table.  You need to reformat the values so that they can be parsed as a time, how should the single numbers be interpreted - Whats `7` and `6.5`?

Comment: Show us sample table data for both columns at the same time. And also show use the expected result.

Comment: It is a bad idea to store times as strings. Now the first task is validating the data. You must make rules which formats you consider valid and which not. '24:00' for instance is probably invalid, right? Then you'd have to make the rules how to interprete the data ('6.5'  = 6:30?). Then where is the date part? The time span from 6:00 to 7:00 can be one hour or twentyfive hours or whatever.

Comment: @Linkan yes both are from the same table, i'm working on a table some other noob created

Answer (score 1):

You data *looks* like it contains hours in various formats.  The "14.75" suggests that a decimal point is decimal hours.

I would suggest converting all to decimal hours.  So, something like this:

```
select (case when col like '%:%'
             then cast(regexp_substr(col, '[^:]', 1, 1) as decimal(10, 2)) + cast(right(col, 2) as decimal(10, 2)) / 100
             else cast(col as decimal(10, 2))
        end)
```

You can then get the time difference by converting both and taking the difference -- you will get decimal hours.

Comment: I tried this : 
`select (case when start_time like '%:%'
             then extract(hour from start_time) + extract(minute from start_time) / 60.0
             else cast(start_time as decimal(10, 2))
       end) as cr 
 from pmcaldt`
I get this error:

`ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source`

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @FarzadSoltani . . . I confused myself somehow.  The column is a string, so it needs string functions, not date/time functions.

Answer (score -1):

```
select to_date(start_time,'hh24:mi')-to_date(end_time,'hh24:mi') FROM table_name;
```

Comment: This could only work if alle the dates were in format hh24:mi

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13797624)

Comment: @H.Pauwelynツ: I believe that the problem of this answer is different from containing being a link-only answer

Comment: @Aleksej: I know that but there is no option to choose code only answers. So I think link only is the best alternative.